# Swift - Passing data coming from an API to another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, segue, viewcontroller

Please check the below code:

```
 @IBAction func sendActivationCode(_ sender: UIButton) {
     service.Register(phoneNumber: self.mobileNumberTxt.text!, callback: { (response) in
        self.setCustomerValues(response: response)
      })
 }

 func setCustomerValues(response: [String:Any]) {
      registrationToken = (response["token"]! as! String)
      code = response["code"] as! Int
 }

 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "toStep2" {
             let vc = segue.destination as! Step2ViewController
             vc.registrationToken = registrationToken
       }
 }
```

The **problem** is: prepare function is executed before `setCustomerValues` and I cannot use `registrationToken` variable in `Step2ViewController.swift` because it's nil.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of connecting your segue from the button to Step2ViewController, connect it from the view controller. This way the segue will not automatically be performed when the button is touched.

Then call performSegue from within your setCustomerValues callback to perform the segue explicitly after getting the registration token. Note that if the callback is not on the main thread, you will need to dispatch_async to the main thread before calling performSegue.

Answer (score 0):

You should push viewcontroller after `self.setCustomerValues(response: response)`. Don't push viewcontroller when `sendActivationCode`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to come out of this problem is to create an IBAction method from your button on a Touch Up Inside Event and not create any Segues on 'action' of your button.

Use the following code:

```
@IBAction func sendActivationCode(_ sender: UIButton) {

         service.Register(phoneNumber: self.mobileNumberTxt.text!, callback: {
         (response) in

            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Step2ViewController") as! Step2ViewController
            vc.registrationToken = (response["token"]! as! String)
            vc.code = response["code"] as! Int
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
         })
 }
```